# Creating an instance from assembly throws a memory leak

Tags: .net, reflection, memory-leaks

I have a desktop application where i need to load some dll using reflection in a different AppDomain, call a method and unload the AppDomain. I have correctly developed it, however the number of assemblies i need to load and unload has been increased recently, and now, after loading 3 dll, when i try to load the 4th dll I get this exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception occurred on startup type '<Module>'. ---> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This often indicates that other memory is corrupt.

en .cctor()

--- End of monitoring the inner exception stack ---

en System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

en System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

en System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

en System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)

en System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

en System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)

en System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)

en BankIntegration.ReflectionCaller.CallInternal(String dll, String typename, String method, Object[] parameters)

en BankIntegration.ReflectionCaller.CallInternal(String dll, String typename, String method, Object[] parameters)

en BankIntegration.ReflectionCaller.Call(String pathToDLL, String typename, String method, Object[] parameters)

en BankIntegration.DllManager.init_bank_conectors(Server service)

en BankIntegration.frmClient..ctor(Server service, String dllPath, Int64 idclient)

en AVISync.frmInit.Button_clicked(Object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
```

After searching on the net, i can't even figure what's the problem. If I debug the application on visual studio it works properly. It only appear on the published application. This is the relevant code:

'DLLManager:

```
For Each bean As BankIntegration.AppUtil.bankBean In aux
        Dim dllPath As String = Path.Combine(DLL_FILES_DIR, bean.DllName)
        Dim download As Boolean = False

        If File.Exists(dllPath) Then
            Dim info As BankInterfaces.beans.DLLInfo = ReflectionCaller.Call(dllPath, bean.DllNameSpace & ".Connector", BankInterfaces.Util.BANKINTERFACE_NAMES.getDLLInfo, Nothing)
            'Irrelevant code here'
            info = Nothing
            'Irrelevant code here'
        End If

            'Irrelevant code here'
        GC.Collect()
    Next
```

'ReflectionCaller

```
Public Shared Function [Call](ByVal pathToDLL As String, ByVal typename As String, ByVal method As String, ByVal ParamArray parameters As Object()) As Object
    Dim permissions As New Security.PermissionSet(Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted)
    Dim adSetup As New AppDomainSetup()
    adSetup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim dom As AppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid.ToString, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, adSetup, permissions)
    Dim ld As ReflectionCaller = DirectCast(dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, GetType(ReflectionCaller).FullName), ReflectionCaller)
    Dim result As Object = ld.CallInternal(pathToDLL, typename, method, parameters)

    AppDomain.Unload(dom)
    dom = Nothing
    ld = Nothing
    GC.Collect()
    Return result
End Function

Private Function CallInternal(dll As String, typename As String, method As String, parameters As Object()) As Object
    Dim a As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(dll)
    Dim o As Object = a.CreateInstance(typename) '<-- This line throws the exception after a few iterations'
    Dim t As Type = o.[GetType]()
    Dim m As Reflection.MethodInfo = t.GetMethod(method)
    Dim result As Object = m.Invoke(o, parameters)

    a = Nothing
    o = Nothing
    t = Nothing
    m = Nothing
    GC.Collect()
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with memory leaks. It is an unmanaged crash.

Comment: @usr First of all, i thought that had to be a problem with the dll. However when i changed the order in which are they loaded, it had the same problem. It always crashes on the 4th dll. Also, the exception says: "Attempted to read or write protected memory". I think that has to be a problem with the unload, which continues blocking the memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days searching on the net i have been able to resolve the error. This is the solution for anyone on my situation.

1. The classes you want to load by reflection have to implement the IDisposable interface.
2. These classes have to override the Dispose method. In this method, simply force the garbage collector:

   ```
   GC.Collect(3)
   GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
   ```

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for, but did you invoke the overridden dispose through a using(){} clause, or just manually when you were done?

Comment: In my case, I called them manually, but I think that disposing it through `using` would work exactly the same.

Comment: but without casting to an object or interface that defines dispose explicitly, how can you call dispose() on the Object created by `Dim o As Object = a.CreateInstance(typename)` ?

Comment: I was wrong, i didn't called dispose manually :) I asked this nearly a year ago, and I cannot review the project which used that code. I cannot remember the exact code I used on release version.