# itextsharp 5.5.9 access violation exception in version.cs

Tags: pdf, itext, access-violation

I use itextsharp 5.5.9 for pdf generation and intermittently 
I get access violation exception (0xC0000005) with this call stack:

```
1 iTextSharp.text.Version.GetInstance()+74 (0x40ec44fc) 
2 iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument+PdfInfo.AddProducer()+16 (0x40ec4446) 
3 iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument..ctor()+102 (0x40ec429a) 
4 iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(iTextSharp.text.Document, System.IO.Stream)+1e (0x40ec3d4e)
```

any Idea how to fix this ?

ps.: one possible scenario is this but I'm not sure about it:

[Creating an instance from assembly throws a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802681/creating-an-instance-from-assembly-throws-a-memory-leak)

Comment: Can you give a hint how to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add code that reproduces this issue?